# Sorting A Character Dataframe According to desired way

Tags: r

I have a dataframe k which contains following strings in the same order:

```
6 to 12 months    
12 to 24 months    
36 to 60 months    
60 to 96 months    
0 to 6 months      
24 to 36 months    
96 to 120 months   
120 months & above.
```

When I apply the `sort` command it sorts by the integer values For eg. the string `120 months and above` is placed before `6-12 months`. Can anyone tell me how to sort it like below using some R command:

```
0 to 6 months      
6 to 12 months
12 to 24 months    
24 to 36 months
36 to 60 months
60 to 96 months
96 to 120 months   
120 months & above.
```

Comment: `order <- c(4,1,2,6,3,4,7,8)` then reorder using `x2 <- x[order]`

Comment: Are you asking how to sort this particular list, or any list with similar values? Passing a custom sorting (ordering) function is not obvious in R.

Comment: This post does something similar https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280285.html the key point is that you will probably do a string split to get the first number then convert it to numeric so it can be sorted as a number.

Comment: @anotherfred I am asking about sorting any list with similar values?

Comment: `gtools` has a very nice function for that. Try `gtools::mixedsort(df$string)`

Comment: @Sotos thank you for letting me know about that function! It would be a simpler choice for OP, although it sounds like they wouldn't benefit from such a 'black box'

Comment: @anotherfred I disagree. If the OP's goal is to make that ordering fast and effortless (which is usually the case), then I 'd say that this function is spot on!

Comment: @Sotos indeed, but looking at their comments, their R knowledge, at least, is benefitting

Answer (score 0):

When the custom sort does not work, you need to `manually specify the order`. Create a factor with your specified order, and `sort` it. Works, even if the array does not contain the group you mention in order.

```
col1 = c("6 to 12 months", 
        "12 to 24 months", 
        "36 to 60 months", 
        "60 to 96 months", 
        "0 to 6 months", 
        "24 to 36 months", 
        "96 to 120 months", 
        "120 months & above")

order <- c("0 to 6 months", 
         "6 to 12 months", 
         "12 to 24 months", 
         "24 to 36 months", 
         "36 to 60 months", 
         "60 to 96 months",
         "96 to 120 months",
         "120 months & above")
col2 <- factor(col1, levels = order)
sort(col2)
```

Just make sure that the `order` contains all the possible values in your array. This example looks very trivial because the input vector is unique. If the input is of length 100, with these 8 possible values then it makes sense.

When there are many more such partitions, use this

```
names(sort(sapply(col1, function(x)
  as.integer(stringr::str_split(x, pattern = ' ')[[1]][1]))))
```

Both the methods give the same output. I would prefer the first method because it is much less prone to mistakes.

Comment: What if inspite of 8 there are 100 strings, it will be tiresome to set the order manually?

Comment: you mean like 100 different groups? `0-6`, `6-8` and so on?

Comment: yes like that if we a lot of groups then manually typing it will be tiresome.

Comment: First of all, that would be a very unusual case. In those cases, sort based on the first number of each string. `names(sort(sapply(col1, function(x) as.integer(stringr::str_split(x, pattern = ' ')[[1]][1]))))`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
require(stringr)

k <- c("6 to 12 months",    
       "12 to 24 months",    
       "36 to 60 months",   
       "60 to 96 months",  
       "0 to 6 months", 
       "24 to 36 months",
       "96 to 120 months",
       "120 months & above")

index <- sapply(seq_along(k), function(x) stringr::str_split(k, pattern = "\\s")[[x]][1])

df <- data.frame(k, index = as.numeric(index))

df[order(index), ]
```

I think you can scale this to a category of any size (as long as the first part of the string follows some order).

Comment: Can you please explain this function sapply(seq_along(k), function(x) stringr::str_split(k, pattern = "\\s")[[x]][1]) and what it does by passing these arguments?

Comment: To find out more about any function, enter a question mark followed by the function name at the R console, e.g. `?sapply`.  Here is an excellent guide to the apply functions to get you started https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/5316882 . The `stringr:str_split` part splits up a character string.

Comment: Hi Praveen, `stringr` is a package from the `tidyverse`, a set of packages that makes your life much easier in many areas (including data wrangling!). `sapply` is part of the apply family in base R. It enables you to apply a funciton over a vector or list. `lapply`will return you a list whereas `sapply` will return you a vector. The function `stringr::str_split()` splits each element of the vector `k` into parts according to some pattern. In this case, `pattern = "\\s"`, I am splitting each element of the vector `k` by one space (`\\s`). The number  `[[1]]` is the first element of the split

Comment: I would also follow @anotherfred 's advice.